# FirePHP not working with Zend's json action helper

Tags: json, zend-framework, xmlhttprequest, firebug, firephp

my FirePHP is working in Firebug 1.8. Did copy over the new core files.

However, when I use the following in the action

```
My_FirePHP::info('test');
    $this->_helper->json($result);
```

of a jQuery post XMLHttpRequest, it does not work.

I'm not too familiar with this to be sure where I'm going wrong. Any assistance appreciated.

PS: My_FirePHP uses Zend's logger, if that helps:

```
protected function __construct()
{
    $logger = new Zend_Log();
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Firebug();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON Helper stops execution of the request handler before the FirePHP headers are written to the response. Just call flush before invoking the JSON helper:

```
// if Firebug is enabled:
Zend_Wildfire_Channel_HttpHeaders::getInstance()->flush();

// proceed as usual
$this->_helper->json($response);
```